# Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for AWS SimpleDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to create a user account for Amazon Web Services to limit my risk if the credentials are compromised.

I have set up a test user with credentials and am trying to create a custom permission so these credentials can only be used for an extremely limited purpose.  It is then asking me for an ARN with the tooltip shown.  I have no idea how to format it.

- Is the account id the same as my account number? Format of `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX`
- If my domain is TestDomain
- I'm not sure what to put for region at all...

Should my ARN look like this?
arn:aws:sdb:::domain/

Or?
`<region>:XXXX-XXXX-XXXX:TestDomain`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> Is the account id the same as my account number? Format of
>   XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

Yes.. avoid hyphens while entering.

> If my domain is TestDomain

domain/testDomain

> I'm not sure what to put for region at all...

You can provide one out of five region end points --
   1. US East (Northern Virginia)
   2. US West (Northern California)
   3. EU (Ireland)
   4. Asia Pacific (Singapore)
   5. Asia Pacific (Tokyo)

> my ARN look like

"arn:aws:sdb:us-east-1:123456789012:domain/testDomain"

Answer (score 3):

> arn:aws:sdb:ap-southeast-1:9999-9999-9999:domain/testDomain

I've tried the above format. It works.

Answer (score 3):

From [official docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingIAMWithSDB.html):

> The ARN format for domains follows this format:
>
> ```
> arn:aws:sdb:<region>:<account_ID>:domain/<domain_name>
> ```
>
> The <region> is
>   required and can be any of the individual Regions Amazon SimpleDB
>   supports (e.g., us-east-1), or * to represent all Regions. The
>   <region> must not be blank.
>
> **Example**
>
> Following is an ARN for a domain named Domain1 in the us-east-1
>   region, belonging to AWS Account 111122223333.
>
> ```
> arn:aws:sdb:us-east-1:111122223333:domain/Domain1
> ```